# How to get the current document of an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a complex code that travels inside windows and iframes (yes, windows cause I open some windows with window.open sometimes and also travel inside iframes) and when some condition apply I get an element from inside of those iframes (they usually are DIVs and SPANs).

So, I have the element that I want in the object "$(this)" so from the parent window how can I know the "document" element that has this element? I need to get the "document" element that has "$(this)" and set some attributes to it.

I tried $(this).parents(document) but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

If `this` refers to an element (such that `$(this)` would give you a jQuery wrapper around it) or indeed any `Node`, then `this.ownerDocument` is a reference to the document the element is in (`null` if it's not in a document). Details in [`ownerDocument` in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-ownerdocument).

Comment: Sometimes I dont have "this", I have the element set in a variable like element = $(this)    and I have only access to "element" variable. How can I acess its document?

Comment: @Samul: Whenever you have a jQuery set, you can access the contents of that set just like you can the contents of an array. So if you've done `element = $(this)`, then `element[0]` is the raw element, and `element[0].ownerDocument` is its owner document (if it's in a document). You can probably also do `element.prop("ownerDocument")` since when you only give it one argument, `prop` accesses the property with the matching name on the first element in the set.

Comment: But then the jQuery object that comes may be `$(document)` and `$(document).prop("ownerDocument")` is null. :-( Don't have any idea how to fix this. To be clear, I am inside a function that accepts the jQuery object as an argument.